# Chrome has DELETED our addon because of an error

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We are completely outraged!

Because of some recent changes in the security policy or whatever our addon was DELETED from ALL the users.

There was no warning, no notification, NOTHING.

This was the problem in our Manifest file:
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' chrome-extension:// https://; object-src 'self'",

It worked like this for years..

And this is the error when trying to install it:

Failed to load extension from: 
Invalid value for 'content_security_policy': Both 'script-src' and 'object-src' directives must be specified (either explicitly, or implicitly via 'default-src'), and both must whitelist only secure resources. You may include any of the following sources: "'self'", "'unsafe-eval'", "http://", "http:// localhost", or any "https://" or "chrome-extension://" origin. For more information, see http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

When this row is removed it works fine.

We want Google to fix it now. Add-on is a basic part of our product, without it our product is not as useful. We have invested money in it. This is not acceptable for us that Google will just take and remove it from all our users.

1. How do we contact Google for this? I couldn't find any way to contact them. We want them to fix this issue and reinstall the addon to all the users that had it. We don't care how they are gonna do it. They deleted it, so they should deal with it now.
2. What is the problem with that line and how do we fix it? our add-on is changing the Chrome new tab and it seems like without it, it stops working.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Let me say a few things: 1. You disobeyed the rules and Google tried to protect the users. This is the correct action to take. 2. Stackoverflow is not a platform to rant about Googles policies. 3. Give your question a meaningful title and ask programming questions only on this site ("how do I contact Google" is not a programming question)

Comment: 1. Hey Stefan, Google should have informed us if our addon is disobeying some rules, before posting it on it's store. If we would know that we wouldn't do it. This addon is up for a long time and has lots of users.  There is no justification for such a thing. we would see how you would not "rant" if your business would be damaged, because of some stupidity like this.
2. There is a programming question also

Comment: sure, this may be frustrating, but it's still the wrong platform. Here we deal programming questions only. So I suggest to stick to the convention and adjust your question.

Comment: I know, I know. It just was not easy for me to write this post without getting angry :)

Comment: @whatever61 This behavior is a bug and will soon be fixed, see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=432227. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Note: the problem is caused by the fact that your csp string is syntactically incorrect, but was tolerated. When the validation of the string was made stricter, your syntactically invalid CSP string was rejected by the extension validator, causing Chrome to refuse your extension.

Comment: Rob W, is there a way now to return the users that have their addons deleted? This is a big headache for us now..

Comment: also, can you confirm that this is a correct syntax (everything seems to be working):
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js; object-src 'self'",

Comment: @whatever61 Put an @-sign before my name, otherwise I won't get notified of your comment. The correct CSP is `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"`. However you don't need to relax the CSP at all, bundle jQuery with your extension and load jQuery.js from your extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the problem with that line and how do we fix it? our add-on is changing the Chrome new tab and it seems like without it, it stops working.

`chrome-extension://` and  `https://` is the problem. First off, it's a syntax error. The correct syntax would be `https://*`.

Second you're supposed to *specify* a small set of domains that are allowed to run code. You're supposed to specify one or two websites from which scripts can be loaded.

For example: `https://domainweloadscriptsfrom.com`

[Google has a whole section on what is and isn't allowed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing).

Comment: Thanks! going to check it tomorrow morning. Will keep you posted.

Comment: We have solved the issue by adjusting the "https://". Thanks!